Removing Values in Multiple Columns
I need some help with creating a vba code that delete the entire row if the value of one cell in column L is equal to zero and if the value on the cell on its left which in the column K is also zero or blank. On the other hand, if the value of one cell in column L is equal to zero and if the value on the cell on its left is not equal to zero or blank, just proceed to deleting the zero value in Column L. Also, if one cell in column G is equal to zero also delete the entire row, if it's equal to blank or not equal to zero then do nothing. Kindly see below for my code. I honestly don't know how to put the second condition and third condition.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range, rg3 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Source")

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       With ActiveSheet

       Set rg1 = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("K"))
       Set rg2 = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("L"))
          n = rg1.Rows.Count
          n2= rg2.Rows.Count        
          For i = n To 1 Step -1
          For i2 = n2 To 1 Step -1

        If Not IsError(rg2.Cells(i2, 1).Value) Then
            If rg2.Cells(i2, 1).Value = 0 And rg1.Cells(i, 1).Value = 0 or "" Then          rg2.Rows(i2).EntireRow.Delete

        End If
       
    Next
    
   End With

MsgBox "Zero Values Removed", vbInformation

End Sub



Use a nested If clause
For a single column range, .Cells(i,1) is equalient to .Cells(i)

Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Source")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rg1 = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("K"))
        Set rg2 = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("L"))
    End With
    n = rg1.Rows.Count
    For i = n To 1 Step -1
        If rg2.Cells(i).Value = 0 Then
            If rg1.Cells(i).Value = 0 Or Len(rg1.Cells(i).Value) = 0 Then
                rg1.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                rg2.Cells(i).Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Zero Values Removed", vbInformation
End Sub



If there's a large dataset on the sheet, it's more efficient to collect all cells and apply changes all at once.

Sub Demo2()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range
    Dim resetRng As Range, delRowRng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Source")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rg1 = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("K"))
        Set rg2 = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("L"))
    End With
    n = rg1.Rows.Count
    For i = n To 1 Step -1
        If rg2.Cells(i).Value = 0 Then
            If rg1.Cells(i).Value = 0 Or Len(rg1.Cells(i).Value) = 0 Then
                If delRowRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRowRng = rg1.Cells(i)
                Else
                    Set delRowRng = Application.Union(delRowRng, rg1.Cells(i))
                End If
            Else
                If resetRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set resetRng = Cells(i)
                Else
                    Set resetRng = Application.Union(resetRng, rg2.Cells(i))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If delRowRng Is Nothing Then
        delRowRng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    If resetRng Is Nothing Then
        resetRng.Value = ""
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Zero Values Removed", vbInformation
End Sub


Update:

Question:  if I would like to add one more condition where in if the one cell in column G is equal to zero then also delete the entire row. However, if one cell in column G is blank then do nothing

Sub Demo3()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range, rg0 As Range ' **
    Dim resetRng As Range, delRowRng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Source")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rg0 = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("G"))
        Set rg1 = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("K"))
        Set rg2 = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("L"))
    End With
    n = rg1.Rows.Count
    For i = n To 1 Step -1
        If rg0.Cells(i).Text = 0 Then
            If delRowRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRowRng = rg1.Cells(i)
            Else
                Set delRowRng = Application.Union(delRowRng, rg1.Cells(i))
            End If 
        End If
        If rg2.Cells(i).Value = 0 Then
            If rg1.Cells(i).Value = 0 Or Len(rg1.Cells(i).Value) = 0 Then
                If delRowRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRowRng = rg1.Cells(i)
                Else
                    Set delRowRng = Application.Union(delRowRng, rg1.Cells(i))
                End If
            ElseIf Len(rg1.Cells(i).Value) > 0 Then
                If resetRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set resetRng = rg2.Cells(i)
                Else
                    Set resetRng = Application.Union(resetRng, rg2.Cells(i))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not delRowRng Is Nothing Then
        delRowRng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    If Not resetRng Is Nothing Then
        resetRng.Value = ""
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Zero Values Removed", vbInformation
End Sub


Hello, if I would like to add one more condition where in if the one cell in column G is equal to zero then also delete the entire row. However, if one cell in column G is blank then do nothing. How will I be able to perform all 3 conditions in one macro?

Changed code are marked with **.

Thank you so much for your help! However, I am getting an error message with this code highlighted in yellow resetRng.Value = "" saying "object variable or with block variable not set"

There are some typo in the code. Pls try the updated code.

I really do appreciate your help but I think my explanation was confusing. The third condition wherein if one cell in column G is equal to zero and etc. is not connected with column K and Column L. So the first condition is if one cell in column L is zero and the cell on its left which is in column K is zero or blank then delete entire row. On the other hand, if the value of one cell in column L is equal to zero and if the value on the cell on its left is not equal to zero or blank, just proceed to deleting the zero value in Column L.

For the second condition or rule, if one cell in column G is equal to zero then proceed to deleting the entire row. On the other hand, if the one cell in column g is not equal to zero or if its blank then do nothing. This only applies in column G.
So the catch is I want to execute both rule in click. Sorry for the inconvenience. Hope you'll bear with me.

Providing clarification on all conditions outlined in the original post can help streamline the process of finding the correct solution, ultimately saving time. Pls try the updated code.

This will be noted. Apologies for the inconvenience this may cause.
As for the code, I guess it's already working as supposed to however in column G it also deletes the entire rows of cells that are blank or empty.

deletes the entire rows of cells that are blank or empty For those rows, does it meet the 2nd conditions on Col K and Col L?

It doesn't meet the condition on column K or L. It has values in column K and L. I guess the reason why it is being deleted was because excel is treating those empty cells as zero in column G

Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.
How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
It's difficlut to answer the question w/o sample data.

You may try If rg0.Cells(i).Text = 0 Then

I guess everything is working fine now. You're the best!!! Thank you so much for your patience!!!

Delete Rows Vs Clear Cells
Before

After

Main
Sub DeleteRowsVsClearCells()

    Dim zrg As Range, zData As Variant, bData As Variant
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("File Source")
        Set zrg = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("L"))
        zData = zrg.Value
        bData = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("K")).Value
    End With
          
    Dim rgDelete As Range, rgClear As Range, Value As Variant, r As Long
          
    For r = 1 To UBound(zData, 1)
        Value = zData(r, 1)
        If IsNumberZero(Value) Then
            Value = bData(r, 1)
            If IsBlankOrNumberZero(Value) Then
                BuildRange rgDelete, zrg.Cells(r)
            Else
                BuildRange rgClear, zrg.Cells(r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
                            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If Not rgDelete Is Nothing Then rgDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    If Not rgClear Is Nothing Then rgClear.ClearContents
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Zeros and blanks removed.", vbInformation

End Sub

Help

The term "blank cells" refers to empty cells and all other cells whose length is zero.
Functions IsBlankOrNumberZero and IsEmptyOrNumberZero call the function IsNumberZero.
The variable CellValue indicates that the value was read from a cell when VBA classifies any number as a Double or Currency data type.

Function IsBlankOrNumberZero(CellValue As Variant) As Boolean
    Select Case True
        Case IsNumberZero(CellValue), Len(CStr(CellValue)) = 0
            IsBlankOrNumberZero = True
    End Select
End Function

Function IsNumberZero(CellValue As Variant) As Boolean
    Select Case VarType(CellValue)
        Case vbDouble, vbCurrency
            If CellValue = 0 Then IsNumberZero = True
    End Select
End Function

Sub BuildRange(ByRef BuiltRange As Range, AddRange As Range)
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set BuiltRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set BuiltRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Sub

Not Used!
Function IsEmptyOrNumberZero(CellValue As Variant) As Boolean
    Select Case True
        Case IsEmpty(CellValue), IsNumberZero(CellValue)
            IsEmptyOrNumberZero = True
    End Select
End Function

